# Null space and Matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-works

http://studyguide.pk/Past%20Papers/CIE/International%20A%20And%20AS%20Level/9231%20-%20Further%20Mathematics/9231_s03_qp_1.pdf

I would like to know the method to answer question 8. I have been having difficulties with finding the basis for the null space of a matrix although I know the basic method. Also, in the second part of the question I have no clue as to how I should proceed to find p and q. I would appreciate it if someone could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Row reduction leads to the form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&-2&3\\
0&1&3&5\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
hence the matrix has rank $2$.

To find a basis for the null space, proceed with row reduction *upwards*. One gets:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1&8\\
0&1&3&5\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
To solve for $A\,\mathbf x=0$, this last form shows that the main unknowns are $x,y\mkern1.5mu$; they can be calculated in function of $z$ and $t$. Indeed:
$$\begin{cases}x=-z-8t,\\y=-3z-5t\end{cases}, \text{whence}\enspace \begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z\\t
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-z-3t\\-3z-3t\\z\\t
\end{bmatrix}=-z\begin{bmatrix}
1\\3\\-1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
-t\begin{bmatrix}
3\\3\\0\\-1
\end{bmatrix}.$$